# Find the Exact Value of the following Cosine Function

Tags: trigonometry

Determine the exact value of $\cos(-5\pi/4)$

I know:

$\cos(\theta)=x/1$,

$5\pi/4$ on the unit circle is $225^\circ$.

Therefore $\cos (225^\circ)=x/1$.

In order to find the exact value I need to find the reference angle.

Here is my first question:

- Do I use the angle $5\pi/4$ on the unit circle, equaling $225^\circ$ 
  ?
- Or, since it is negative, assume that $-5\pi/4 = 3\pi/4$ (going
  clockwise)?

I think I know where to go once I have the reference angle.
Any hints as to how I would find that?

---

EDIT:

So, if $-5\pi/4 = 3\pi/4$, and $3\pi/4 = 135^{\circ}$

The reference angle is $45^{\circ}$

$cos(45^{\circ}) = 1/\sqrt 2$

$\cos$ is negative in quadrant II

$= 1/{-\sqrt{2}}$

How does that look?

Comment: Please edit equations if you can/want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second one. Negative means you go backwards (clockwise) so -5π/4 would be 3π/4.

After edit: That seems right :)

Comment: Great, exactly what I needed. See edit.